# ServiceStack, LeftJoin query

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have this SQL code, and I want this converted to ormlite - but I don't know how to do this the best way.

```
SELECT  *
FROM Job 
INNER JOIN Emp ON Job.JobAnsvarID = Emp.EmpId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT JobId, MIN(TimeReg.RegDate) AS TimeMinDate FROM TimeReg WHERE RegHrs IS NOT NULL AND JournNo = 0 GROUP BY JobId) AS t ON t.JobId = Job.JobID
WHERE   NOT (t.TimeMinDate IS NULL)
```

I know I could use CustomJoin and UnsafeWhere, but if possible I want to avoid using hardcoded text.

Right now I have this, but again, I want to avoid hardcoded text.

```
var ev = Db.From<Job>();
ev.CustomJoin("LEFT JOIN (SELECT {TimeReg.JobId}, MIN({TimeReg.RegDate}) AS MinDate FROM {TimeReg} WHERE {TimeReg.RegHrs} IS NOT NULL AND {TimeReg.JournNo} = 0 GROUP BY {TimeReg.JobId}) AS t ON t.JobId = {Job.JobID}"
            .ReplaceAll("{Job.JobID}", GetQuotedColumnName<Job>(x => x.Id, true))
            .ReplaceAll("{TimeReg.JobId}", GetQuotedColumnName<TimeRegDTO>(x=>x.JobId, true))
            .ReplaceAll("{TimeReg.RegDate}", GetQuotedColumnName<TimeRegDTO>(x => x.RegistrationDate, true))
            .ReplaceAll("{TimeReg.RegHrs}", GetQuotedColumnName<TimeRegDTO>(x => x.Hours, true))
            .ReplaceAll("{TimeReg.JournNo}", GetQuotedColumnName<TimeRegDTO>(x => x.JournalNumber, true))
            .ReplaceAll("{TimeReg}", GetQuotedTableName<TimeRegDTO>()));
```

GetQuotedColumnName just take the Alias name from the DTO and use this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No OrmLite doesn't have a Typed API for Custom Joins on Sub Queries just [IN SubSelect queries](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html).

Instead of replacing HTML I would just use C# string interpolation, also a simpler Typed approach could be to use `nameof`, e.g:

```
var q = Db.From<Job>();
q.CustomJoin($"LEFT JOIN (SELECT {nameof(Job.Id)} ...")
```

Which you'll be able to use if your properties aren't aliased or you're using a custom naming convention.

Otherwise to make the use-case for this a little nicer I've added new `.Column<Table>()` and `.Table<T>()` extension methods in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/04aea0fbe939cc4bb9edd4af9de1525e8b43122f) which will let you use Typed APIs in your custom SQL, e.g:

```
q.CustomJoin($"LEFT JOIN (SELECT {q.Column<Job>(x => x.Id)} ...")
q.CustomJoin($"LEFT JOIN (SELECT {q.Column<Job>(nameof(Job.Id))} ...")

q.CustomJoin($"LEFT JOIN (SELECT {q.Column<Job>(x => x.Id, tablePrefix:true)} ...")
//Equivalent to:
q.CustomJoin($"LEFT JOIN (SELECT {q.Table<Job>()}.{q.Column<Job>(x => x.Id)} ...")
```

This change is available from v5.0.3 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: How would you solve the UnsafeWhere statement I have?

Comment: @MortenHausted What `UnsafeWhere` satement?

Comment: Nice, I forgot to add it in the question - My bad!
ev.UnsafeWhere("NOT (t.MinDate IS NULL)");

Comment: @MortenHausted There's limited support when using an alias but you should be able to do something like `q.Where<Job>(x => Sql.JoinAlias(nameof(Job.MinDate), "t") != null)`