# Convert JoinSqlBuilder to SqlExpressionVisitor

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a function that returns SqlExpressionVisitor to be used later as an input to Select statements.

```
private SqlExpressionVisitor<Account> GetExpressionVisitor (int id, bool  detailed, SqlExpressionVisitor<Account> ev)
{
    if (!detailed)
    {
        ev = ev.Where (a => a.Id == id);
    }
    else
    { 
        // need to do join with another table via JoinSqlBuilder to query more information and then pack results in the ev object ... 
    }
    return ev;
}
```

Any idea how to convert JoinSqlBuilder to SqlExpressionVisitor or how to edit SqlExpressionVisitor and inject the join query in an effective way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve but you can add use the [Typed API for Joins](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-sqlexpression-support-for-joins) similar to your typed `Where` expression. Otherwise if using a Typed API isn't possible you can use the [CustomJoin API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48216950/85785) to add a string JOIN expression to your query, e.g:

```
var q = Db.From<Job>();
q.CustomJoin($"LEFT JOIN (SELECT {nameof(Job.Id)} ...")
```